# Running unit test is taking a very long time in VS2015

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I'm trying to create a unit test for my UWP project. But whenever I run a test it does not complete. The test explorer shows a busy indeterminate progress bar forever.

Here's what I did:

1. Create a new UWP app
2. Right click on the solution add new project
3. Add a Unit Test App (Universal Windows)
4. In the UnitTest1.cs, under TestMethod1, I added an Assert.IsTrue(1==2). 
   using System;
   using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework;

> ```
> namespace UnitTestProject1
> {
>   [TestClass]
>   public class UnitTest1
>   {
>     [TestMethod]
>     public void TestMethod1()
>     {
>       Assert.IsTrue(1 == 2);
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

5. Build the solution so the TestMethod1 will be discovered in the Test Explorer.
6. Right click on TestMethod1 in test explorer then click on "Run selected tests"
7. The output window will shows:

   ------ Discover test started ------

   ========== Discover test finished: 1 found (0:00:00.2065484) ==========

   ------ Run test started ------
8. Test App window shows up, then closes.
9. If you look at the test explorer it shows a progress bar as if it's still loading and the test is still running. I'm stuck here, the test never completed.

[image]

**Update**: I tried restarting the computer and did the same steps this time I got an error, but still not completing the test. Still stuck in the test explorer loading.

***Error DEP3000*** : Attempts to stop the application failed. This may cause the deployment to fail.

Comment: Yes it's just one line. I added the code to my question.

Comment: I've tested your code and it works fine for me; I don't think it is related to the code itself.

Comment: Debug the test instead of running it. Then you can click "pause" and see what is going on.

Comment: Yeah I tried debugging, since I can't stop the test. I created another project and do the same steps except that I did not run the test, I debug it instead. Same thing happened.

Comment: Were any breakpoints hit?

Comment: No, I added a breakpoint to TestMethod1(). I think there's somthing wrong maybe in my configuration or setup of visual studio.

Comment: Question updated. I see an error after restarting the computer and did the same steps.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution? restart of VS or computer does not help

Comment: No but the workaround I did was to use a different runner. Instead of running it in VS, I used this https://github.com/xunit/devices.xunit. The disadvantage of this is that it will launch a UWP app and that's where you'll see your test results. I readlly don't like the idea of launching another app. But for now, that's how I do it until this gets fixed.